# Handling very long forms with Play 2

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0

My application contain big form with 18 fields. It is processed with standard form mapping, like this:

```
val bigForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "id"    -> of[ObjectId],
    "title" -> text,
    // And another 16 fields...
    ...
  )
)
```

And all was well, but today I decided to add one more field and here comes the problem - `mapping` is not able to take more than 18 arguments.

What should I do then? I thinking of combining some fields into the structure, but additional structure requires additional formatter, JSON serializer and deserializer, too much work. I'm looking for a general solution, more fields are likely to appear in the future.

Another solution I'm thinking about is to handle form manually, without `Form`'s.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: Just from a usability perspective, it makes a lot of inputs for your user... you can't divide in several pages ?

Comment: nico_ekito, Form is used to modify complex objects and presented to user in several tabs like `general`, `more advanced` and `advanced`. User often searches for required field, modifies it and clicks save. I think such a long form is ok for now, but I may be wrong.

Comment: What about an autosave for each field ? Sadly, it would require a lot of work, but it may be better from the user perspective ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nested mappings, e.g.

```
val bigForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "id"    -> of[ObjectId],
    "title" -> text,
    "general" -> mapping(
      ...
    )(GeneralInfo.apply)(GeneralInfo.unapply),
    "advanced" -> mapping(
      ...
    )(AdvancedInfo.apply)(AdvancedInfo.unapply)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is using view objects and updating only the part that was submitted (e.g. via separate forms or AJAX):

```
val generalForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "title" -> text,
    ...
  )
)

def updateGeneral(id: ObjectId) = Action { implicit request =>
  MyObject.findById(id).map { myObj =>
    generalForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      fail => BadRequest(...),
      form => {
        val newObj = myObj.copy(title = form.title, ...)
        MyObject.save(newObj)
        Ok(...)
      }
    )
  }.getOrElse(NotFound)
}
```